# I'm needing a beginner's guide on how to set up SSRS from the very beginning for an ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I'm pretty familiar with ASP.NET, and am currently writing an MVC app in ASP.NET.
I'm at the point where I need to integrate reports into my application.
The option I chose to go with (and I'm flexible on this) is SSRS.
I have zero experience in SSRS and it seems that there are a LOT of steps involved in getting that set up, from installing the Report Server, configuring the Report Server, creating a report project in Business Intelligence Development Studio, and publishing the report to the Report Server.  I might have done something wrong in the process since I wasn't sure about half of the configuration settings with Report Server.  Can anyone guide me to a "tutorial" on how to:

1.) Set up and install SSRS properly.  I'm using SQL Server 2008. (Not R2).

2.) Creating and publishing a report to the Report Server.

3.) Being able to access this report from my ASP.NET web application.

I appreciate any responses!!  Thanks!!

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is really easy to install. Not even sure you really need instructions unless you are doing something special. I installed it as part of the base SQL 2008 install and it was straight forward. Here is a link that may help you out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839480(SQL.90).aspx

Once installed, just open the Reporting Service Configuration Manager and you can change any data or settings at a later time. You also see what the links are for that server to get to the reports and where to edit them. FYI, IIS will need to be installed to host front end report page.

2) Browse to the "Report Manager URL". You can get this from the Reporting Service Configuration manager. Default install would probably install it as `http://127.0.0.1/Reports/`, plug in whatever IP but if logged into the server that should work.

From there, you can click on and install "Report Builder" [on top menu bar]. I THINK it installs version 1, if it is version 1, I recommend downloading and installing Report Builder 2.0 from Microsoft [free]? Reports builder 3 is also available but you need R2 for that version. Once you download and install the app you can build all your reports from there and can also link up to your server and auto upload them. Very easy once you install and run this program. No reason for BIDS.

3) Maybe the easiest part! Use the already created "Report Viewer" control in VS. Enter the correct URL path of SSRS in the control and which report to pull and bingo.

Here is a nice walk through for you. From creating reports in Report Builder and accessing them on ASP page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251686(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 parts to this.

a)  Creating a report:

You can install the Reporting Services components into VS.net (or BIDS as VS.net is called by Microsoft in this instance), from here you can connect to a datasource, design, create and preview reports - all from the comfort of your machine. There are even wizards to help you get up and started. You will see these under a new section in the "create new project" dialog called "business intelligence"

What this essentially does is to create a report file (an XML file with an .RDL extension) and a datasource file (.RDS extension)

b) Using the report:

You will need to install the RS components on a server. RS is accessed via http(s) and needs a SQL Server db to store information about the reports. They can both reside on the same box.

The tool for managing the RS site is called 'report manager' and is a web based tool.
http://localhost/reports

Once you have this set up (including security), simply deploy your report from step 1 and you're good to go - you can do this by simply 'right clicking/ deploy' on your new report in VS.net

c) At this point you'll have a good understanding of how it all works so adding the report viewer control to your app will be simple.